# primefaces 6 schedule dateSelect on double click

Tags: events, jsf-2, primefaces, schedule

I'm using the `p:schedule` component from `Primefaces 6.0`.
The event `dateSelect` is fired by a click.

```
<p:schedule ...>
  <p:ajax event="dateSelect" listener="#{scheduleView.onDateSelect}" update="eventDetails" oncomplete="PF('eventDialog').show();" />
```

How can this event be fired only on a `doubleclick` ?

Thanks

Comment: did you try `<p:ajax event="rowDblselect">` from http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html

Comment: Yes I tried that:

javax.servlet.ServletException: /schedule.xhtml @31,138 <p:ajax> Event:rowDblselect is not supported.

Comment: @YagamiLight: Where in the documentation is 'rowDblselect' mentioned for the schedule component? Page 403 does not mention this event at all

Comment: @Kukeltje you can found it i the **Ajax Behavior Events**